# Proper Drawing2D class for NET CF?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, drawing2d

As I recently found out Drawing2D class of NET CF is missing most of it's functionality. Is there a way to expand it with for example "**LinearGradientBrush**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're specifically looking for a replacement for `LinearGradientBrush`, there is a Win32 function called [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here's an example showing how to use it:

[How to: Display a Gradient Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229655.aspx)

Comment: Are there any Drawing2D extension classes for NetCf? Don't want to use unmanaged API.